# Splitting lines automatically at specific distances using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-9.3, algorithm

I have a set of polylines which I need to split at varying distances from their starting points.

In general, I'm looking for a something similar to the SPLIT function within the editor tool. There it is possible to specify a certain line length where the split should be applied.

For instance: I have a line A of 3200m length, that I need to split into two separate geometries, one from 0 til 1700m, and one from 1700m til 3200m.

Can this be done in ArcGIS Desktop?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1. on WinXP with Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ETGeowizards (Polyline->Split Polyline).  If you need to include this in a script or geoprocessing model, ETGeowizards can be pulled into ModelBuilder.

In PostGis you can use [ST_Line_Substring](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html)

Comment: The only restriction would be licence. You can not use ET GeoWizzard in model builder without licence. Manually you could use ET for featureclass containing less than 100 features.

Comment: Too bad: I can't install ETGeowiz at my office. PostGIS also no option for me...I thought about dynamic segmentation which will give me the points for the split. But then I'm stuck with what I just posted down this page: I haven't got access to the split line at point tool.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Data Management tool called [Split Line At Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000) that does exactly this but it requires ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 (or later), and an ArcInfo (later called Advanced) level license:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace="C:/data"
arcpy.SplitLineAtPoint_management("streets.shp","events.shp","splitline_out.shp","20 Meters")
```

Comment: The line at point tool is what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't exist with ArcGis 9.3.1 yet. The line at vertices tool doesn't help much because I end up with  thousandths of splits I don"t need.

Answer (score 3):

I've used this ArcObjects class to split line features before at specific distances.

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/Samples/Editing/Edit%20Commands/Line%20Edit%20Toolbar/clsDivideLineFeatures.htm

Comment: This is a very interesting add-on! Thanks for sharing the information. Do you have ever used it from within a script? I need to apply splits at varying distances to more than 100 lines. So what I need here is to call the "Proportion"-tool with an array of distances. Is that possible? Thanks mate!

Comment: Since you are using 9.3.1, you could either create a VBA macro or a Visual Studio BaseCommand dll.  http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/01c01659-cdf8-4579-9c87-2b965e872d84.htm.  Then you could iterate through your layer, selecting each feature, and spliting the feature maybe by the feature field value (split at distance value).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Sounds like a lot of work though, especially because this is terra incognita for me. Might be easier to find someone with ArcGIS 10 installed and let him/her run the `SplitLineAtPoint_management`-tool.