# split multi line by use of distance field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting lines automatically at specific distances?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25368/splitting-lines-automatically-at-specific-distances)

i have a transect layer with 160 transect . id like to split each transect with specific value from the beginning of the transect . the distance values are store in a field and related to the transects. for example transect 1 : distance value from the beginning is 27.5 meter . transect 2 : 32.4 meter .
how can i split the transects with the distance values in ArcGIS9.3 ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but related to using this site, is I would go back and "accept" answers to some of the other questions you have asked.  This will make people more likely to answer this one.  [How to ask questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: it's not duplicate of post Splitting lines automatically at specified distances . 1- ETgeowizard can't solve the problem . 2- I can't use ArcPy bezcause i use ArcGIS 9.3 and i don't have any knowledge about python .

Comment: The duplication does not relate to the answers, but to the question, which specifically mentions ArcGIS 9.3.1, which you are using.  Since you put no detail in your question related to python, it was logical to include using Python as an option.  If you edit your question to include more detail about what options and experience you have available to you, it will help you get a better answer, and also not have your question marked as a duplicate in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COGO Toolbar to split lines with proportional interval.

Fulll description has posted in my blog: http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/?p=3002

Cheers, Jorge Santos

Comment: COGO does not work because i have 160 transect and id like to find a method that split transects automaticaly . COGO just use Proportion method .