# Perpendicular transect from lowest to highest elevation in gridded data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, transects

I have a gridded dataset that has mean elevations as the centroid value. I would like to create a perpendicular transect line from lowest to highest elevation in this mountainous area. Once I have the transect, I will then pick a set of six or eight grid points from lowest to highest elevation for further analysis.

I tried looking into [Creating perpendicular transects to stream at specified intervals using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20855), but I could not quite understand where to start. So far I know that I can draw a line perpendicular to a polygon.

How can I do this in ArcMap 10.7?

This is how I was explained about it, to draw a perpendicular transect such that I can get a set 6-8 of pixels from low to high elevation within in the study area.

[image]

In reality my study area looks this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Spatial Analyst and/or 3D Analyst licensing?  What have you tried/researched?

Comment: You seem to have a number of steps envisioned. Have you tried to do any of them?  What error have you encountered?

Comment: @PolyGeo, yes I do have spatial analyst. I have looked into [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20855/arcgis-10-create-perpendicular-transects-to-stream-at-specified-intervals), but I could not quite understand where to start. Even the transect tool links provided are not working anymore.

Comment: I know in `ArcMap` you can draw `perpendicular` lines with respect to a polygon, but I don't know how do it in terms of elevation. Another problem is that since the area is very heterogenous.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I'm not understanding *'perpendicular transect'*, can you draw a picture of what your result would ideally look like and edit it into your question. Also are you trying to script this or would an interactive method work for you?

Comment: @MichaelStimson, you are right, I have added a rough sketch based on what I understood from this meeting I had. And when I looked at the study area, the elevation is so heterogenous, even I was confused on how to make a 'perpendicular transect ' for this. If my edits still do not make sense, then I will have some clarity tomorrow and edit the question accordingly. Please don't close the question until then

Comment: @MichaelStimson, an interactive method would work better for me.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to find the lowest and highest elevation by sorting the attribute table, select both, use feature to point to extract the centroids, draw a line between the two points, with the construct points tool add markers (6-8) along said line then add perpendicular lines, snapping to the points and constrained to perpendicular using Ctrl + E, make the lines as long as you like you can always cut them back later, if you like to be neat you can also constrain with Ctrl + L to limit the length - with both constrained a vertex will be added. Intersecting the perpendicular lines with

Comment: your polygons you can pick up the mean elevation for each cell the line passes through which would make it a transect. There is a spatial/3d analyst tool for making a 3d transect if the intersection doesn't meet your requirement which can be viewed in ArcScene and rotated in 3 dimensions to visually asses the transect but I'd want a much finer raster than those cells to get a proper 3d transect. If Ctrl + E/L don't work both perpendicular and limit to length are available by right clicking on the min-max line. Don't panic if your question is closed, any edit puts it in the reopen queue.